# how to groupby and create list of strings

Tags: pandas, list, group-by

I have:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,2],'b':[[1,2,3],[2,5],[3]],'c':['f','df','ere']})
df
    a   b           c
0   1   [1, 2, 3]   f
1   1   [2, 5]      df
2   2   [3]         ere
```

I want to concatenate and create a list on each element:

```
pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2],'b':[[1,2,3,2,5],[3]],'c':[['f', 'df'],['ere']]})
    a   b               c
0   1   [1, 2, 3, 2, 5] [f, df]
1   2   [3]             [ere]
```

I tried:

```
df.groupby('a').agg({'b': 'sum', 'c': lambda x: list(''.join(x))})

a   b               c
1   [1, 2, 3, 2, 5] [f, d, f]
2   [3]             [e, r, e]
```

But it is not quite right.

Any suggesetions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You almost get it right:

```
df.groupby('a', as_index=False).agg({
    'b': 'sum',
    'c': list    # no join needed
})
```

Output:

```
   a                b        c
0  1  [1, 2, 3, 2, 5]  [f, df]
1  2              [3]    [ere]
```